# Latex table does not render via rmarkdown::render

Tags: r

I have an R program building some latex tables. Rendering them from my R program fails.

R program:

```
cat(report1(), report2(), report3(), file = "table.tex")
rmarkdown::render(input = "render.Rmd", 
                    params = list(table = "/path/to/table.tex"))
```

Error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \cellcolor
```

My R markdown:

````
---
output: pdf_document
params:
  table: "/path/to/table.tex"
---

\newpage

```{r setup, include=F}
library("kableExtra")
```

`r readr::read_file(params$table)`
````

Sample table.tex to reproduce

```
\begin{table}

\caption{caption}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|l|l|r|r|r|r}
\hline
header1 & header2 & header3 & header4 & header5 & header6\\
\hline
\hline
\hline
\hline
\hline
\hline
\hline
\hline
\cellcolor[HTML]{B3B3B3}{\textbf{}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{B3B3B3}{\textbf{}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{B3B3B3}{\textbf{}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{B3B3B3}{\textbf{x}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{B3B3B3}{\textbf{x}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{B3B3B3}{\textbf{x}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{B3B3B3}{\textbf{x}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textsuperscript{} footnote}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

If I knit directly from my markdown file in RStudio, it works. If I omit loading kableExtra, knitting fails with the same error.

What's wrong?

**EDIT 1**

Added table.tex to reproduce issue.

**EDIT 2**

The knitting automatically adds includes. `rmarkdown::render`does not.

If I declare packages myself in the Rmd myself with `header-includes: \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{longtable} \usepackage{array} \usepackage{multirow} \usepackage{wrapfig} \usepackage{float} \usepackage{colortbl} \usepackage{pdflscape} \usepackage{tabu} \usepackage{threeparttable} \usepackage{threeparttablex} \usepackage[normalem]{ulem} \usepackage{makecell} \usepackage{xcolor}`, then rendering via rmarkdown::render works, but knitting breaks.

So the question becomes: how can I render a pdf from my R program without having to manage packages myself?

Comment: At a guess, the tables you want to include assume some LaTeX packages are loaded, and your document doesn't load them.  For something more specific, you should post a minimal reproducible example that generates the same error as your real one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known quirk:

https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1851

In essence, kableExtra takes care of adding necessary latex packages when loaded in a new session. A new session is always created when knitting, not from a straight R script. So the straight R script will produce an error unless packages are in the Rmd header. Knitting will fail if packages are given in the header AND `library(kableExtra)` is used in the Rmd.

The solution to satisfy both is this. In the Rmd:

- Specify latex packages with header-includes
- Do NOT load the kableExtra library.